# Before filter on new and create actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a security related, general question about Rails.

Let's assume I have a controller like this:

```
def ProjectsController

  before_action :user_has_paid, :only => [ :new, :create ]  

  ...

  def new
    @project = Project.new
  end

  def create
    @project = current_user.projects.build(project_params)
    if @project.save
      flash[:success] = "Project saved."
      redirect_to projects_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  ...

  private

    def user_has_paid
      if current_user.has_not_paid?
        flash[:notice] = "You must pay first."
        redirect_to payments_path
      end
    end

end
```

From a security point-of-view: Do I need the `before_action` on both the `new` **and** the `create` action?

To save a couple of SQL queries I would like to use it on the `new` action only, but I wonder if that's save or if a malicious user might be able to circumvent the `new` action and create a project anyway, without having paid first.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: "To save a couple of SQL queries" - can you explain a little more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a security perspective you'll definitely want to have the `before_action` on the create action (otherwise a malicious user could user curl or the like to bypass paying). As for whether you have it on the new action will depend on the desired user experience - do you want users trying to request the 'new' view to be immediately redirected (i.e. they don't get to even see the view unless they've paid), or do you want to allow users to see that view (and perhaps just render a warning message about needing to pay before submitting to the create action).

From a performance standpoint, unless the call to `current_user.has_not_paid?` is particularly intensive I wouldn't worry about the extra queries.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use `before_action` for both `new` and `create` action. If you expose API for `ProjectsController`, `POST` request to create project will not be accepted then. So, as far as I understand, checking for both actions will be safe and good choice and not leaving any security hole for further development.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I threw a coin and then marked `neuronaut`'s answer as the correct one.